# Only first letter detecting as false, not others, how can all be looked at?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made the following code but realized there is an error in it that prevents me from successfully finishing the rest of my codes.

the code is:

```
def isvalid(userg, valid_c, size):
'''(list, str, int) -> bool
Given userg, a list of single character strings;
valid_ch, a string; and size, an int;
return True if every character in user_guess list is in
valid_characters and if user_guess is of length guess_size.
Return False otherwise.
>>>isvalid(['A', 'B', 'C'], 'ABCDE', 3)
True
>>>isvalid(['Y', 'G', 'O', 'B'], 'YGOBPR', 4)
True
>>>isvalid(['X', 'G', 'O', 'B'], 'YGOBPR', 4)
False
>>>isvalid(['Y', 'G', 'O', 'B'], 'YGOBPR', 5)
False
>>>valid(['Y', 'G', 'O'], 'GOBPR', 4)
False
'''
for char in userg:
    if len(userg) == size and char in valid_c:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

However, it only works to return False if the very first letter in userg is not in valid_c. For example, isvalid(['Y', 'K', 'O', 'B'], 'YGOBPR', 4) returns true because while 'K' is not in valid_c, it is not in the first position (where the Y is) so it does not recognize it as being wrong/false. If I had isvalid(['K', 'Y', 'O', 'B'], 'YGOBPR', 4) then it would recognize it as False because K is first. Can anyone help me with this please? I tried other things but they did not work. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what the `return` statement does? You should `continue` if the condition is `True` and then `return True` only after all the items have been checked at the end of the *for* loop.

Comment: What you want is `return len(userg) == size and all(char in valid_c for char in userg)`. That is in fact a direct translation of the requirements in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you mean something like?

```
def isvalid(userg, valid_c, size):
     return len(userg) == size and all(char in userg for char in valid_c)
```

Comment: No, not exactly.